# Sharing Image through nfc and storing into database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

How do I share an image through nfc and store it into the database? I have looked into this  [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and only manage to create the peer to peer connection. As for sharing the image, I came across this post and tried running the [demo](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PixPresenter-Code-sharing-39ed631f) but I wasn't able to understand any of the code. Is there a simpler method to doing this?

What I have done so far:

```
 public ExchangeCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

        // Make sure NFC is supported
        if (device != null)
        {
        PeerFinder.TriggeredConnectionStateChanged += OnTriggeredConnectionStateChanged;

            // Start finding peer apps, while making this app discoverable by peers
            PeerFinder.Start();
        }

    }



    StreamSocket _streamSocket;

    void OnTriggeredConnectionStateChanged(object sender, TriggeredConnectionStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.State)
        {
            case TriggeredConnectState.Listening:
                // Connecting as host
                break;
            case TriggeredConnectState.PeerFound:
                // Proximity gesture is complete and user can pull their devices away. Remaining work is to 
                // establish the connection using a different transport, like TCP/IP or Bluetooth
                break;
            case TriggeredConnectState.Connecting:
                // Connecting as a client
                break;
            case TriggeredConnectState.Completed:
                // Connection completed, retrieve the socket over which to communicate
                _streamSocket = args.Socket;
                break;
            case TriggeredConnectState.Canceled:
                break;
            case TriggeredConnectState.Failed:
                // Connection was unsuccessful
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample that does what you want: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PixPresenter-Code-sharing-39ed631f

Essentially the idea is to use `PeerFinder` (like you started with) and then to open a `Socket` between the two peers. The relevant code is in [`PeerConnector.cs`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PixPresenter-Code-sharing-39ed631f/sourcecode?fileId=70591&pathId=1215699850).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, NFC gets complicated.  There's quite a bit of plumbing involved to handle peer-to-peer communication seamlessly.  It's far too much to put into an answer here on the site, so I will have to resort to links.

You can check out this Nokia article and project to work through your understanding of the plumbing.
http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!code-examples/nfc-talk.html

Then you can take a look at this article to add the image transfer functionality.
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Transfer_an_Image_with_NFC